# How to exclude group of characters in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I wanna write a script that returns digits with power of 1. User's inputs are quadratic and normal digits. what I want is described below:

```
input = "+2**5+3+4**8-7"
Output = "3,-7"
```

I tried regex `re.findall(r"[+-]?[0-9]+[^[*][*][2]]", input)` but it doesn't work
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a *negative look-around assertions*, and add boundary anchors:

```
r'(?<!\*\*)-?\b\d+\b(?!\*\*)'
```

The `(?<!...)` syntax only matches at positions where the text before it doesn't match the pattern. Similarly, the `(?!...)` syntax does the same for *following* text. Together they ensure you only match numbers that are not exponents (follow `**`) and not have an exponent (followed by `**`).

The `\b` boundary anchor only matches at the start or end of a string, and anywhere there’s a word character followed by a non-word character or vice versa (so in between `\w\W` or `\W\w`, where `\w` happily includes digits but not arithmetic characters):

```
>>> import re
>>> input = "+2**5+3+4**8-7"
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!\*\*)-?\b\d+\b(?!\*\*)', input)
['3', '-7']
```

Note that I used `\d` to match digits, and removed the `+` from the pattern, since you don't want that in your expected output.

You can play with the expression in the [online regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hcSmMO/1/); e.g. you can try it with numbers > 10 and using a single `*` for multiplication.

If you must support negative exponents, then the above won’t suffice as `...**-42` has `42` match without `**` preceding the digits. In that case an extra negative look-behind before the `-?` that disallows `**-` is needed:

```
r'(?<!\*\*)-?(?<!\*\*-)\b\d+\b(?!\*\*)'
```

(Thanks to [Casimir eg Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) for points my this out and suggesting a solution for it).

However, at this point I’d suggest you switch to just parsing the expression into an [abstract syntax tree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) and then walking the tree to extract the operands that are not part of an exponent:

```
import ast

class NumberExtractor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.numbers = []

    def _handle_number(self, node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Constant):
            if isinstance(node.value, (int, float, complex)):
                return node.value
        elif isinstance(node, ast.Num):
            return node.n

    def visit_UnaryOp(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.op, (ast.UAdd, ast.USub)):
            operand = self._handle_number(node.operand)
            if operand is None:
                return
            elif isinstance(node.op, UAdd):
                self.numbers.append(+operand)
            else:
                self.numbers.add(-operand)

    def visit_Constant(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.value, (int, float, complex)):
            self.numbers.append(node.value)

    def visit_Num(self, node):
        self.numbers.append(node.n)

    def visit_BinOp(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.op, ast.Pow):
            return  # ignore exponentiation
        self.generic_visit(node)  # process the rest

def extract(expression):
    try:
        tree = ast.parse(expression, mode='eval')
    except SyntaxError:
        return []
    extractor = NumberExtractor()
    extractor.visit(tree)
    return extractor.numbers
```

This extracts just the numbers; subtraction won’t produce a negative number:

```
>>> input = "+2**5+3+4**8-7"
>>> extract(input)
[3, 7]
```

Moreover, it can handle arbitrary amounts of whitespace, and much more complex expressions than a regex could ever handle:

```
>>> extract("(10 + 15) * 41 ** (11 + 19 * 17) - 42")
[10, 15, 42]
```

Comment: `**-12`: I'm afraid two lookbehinds are needed for this case (https://regex101.com/r/qZy32F/1)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte ah yes, that’s unfortunate. I’ll ponder it for a bit; limited time at the moment.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte one alternate i think is using alternation, have a pattern to take care about start and end part of string  [`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/jkYOhL/3/)

Comment: @CodeManiac using the Python parser and traversing the AST is definitely a better option there :-)

Comment: You can also use a simple and stupid solutiion: remove all numbers with exponent first.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte and then someone points out you can use `81**(42*17)`, etc.  AST parsing solves all those cases way better.

Comment: @MartijnPieters don't have much context of AST, may be a dumb question but since this is string will the AST be able to know that it's an exponent ?

Comment: @CodeManiac yes, because it is parsed as Python code.

Comment: Thanks. But I've got into another problem: I want my program works even if user inputs multiplied numbers. Like: ```input = " 2**5+3+4**8-7*3"``` and ```output = ["3","-7*3"]``` (I don't care about "3" it could be "+3" too.) Thanks again

Comment: Seems I didn't wrote my regex exactly as same as your pattern :) when I copied it, worked.(codes are in my pc and I'm using mobile for internet)

Answer (score 3):

```
re.findall(r"(?<!\*\*)(?<!\*\*[+-])[+-]?\b[0-9]++(?!\*\*)", input)
```

`(?!\*\*)` is a negative lookahead that makes sure we haven't 2 `*` after digits.

`re` doesn't support posssessive quantifiers, you have to use [PyPi regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/)

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V52lAB/2)

Comment: Python re module doesn't have possessive quantifiers.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I wasn't aware of that, I've just test with regex101.

Comment: Note that even with possessive quantifier support, your pattern will match `**-12` since the `?` isn't possessive too.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Fixed with 2 lookbehind and a word boundary.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a parser and check whatever you need.
I know it is a bit long, but fun :)

```
$ cat lexer.py
import re
from collections import namedtuple

tokens = [
    r'(?P<TIMES>\*)',
    r'(?P<POW>(\+|-)?\d+\*\*\d+)',
    r'(?P<NUM>(\+|-)?\d+)'
    ]

master_re = re.compile('|'.join(tokens))
Token = namedtuple('Token', ['type','value'])
def tokenize(text):
    scan = master_re.scanner(text)
    return (Token(m.lastgroup, m.group())
            for m in iter(scan.match, None))

x = '+2**5+3+4**8-7'

required = []
for tok in tokenize(x):
  if tok.type == 'POW':
      coeff, exp = tok.value.split('**')
      if exp == '1':
          required.append(coeff)
  elif tok.type == 'NUM':
      required.append(tok.value)

print(required)
```

Output:

```
$ python lexer.py
['+3', '-7']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple regex expression

```
re.findall(r'[-\+]\d(?!\*\*)', search_data)
```